# Add method for tracking who referred new users

Tags: users, user-meta

A client wants me to make somthing like user genealogy.  It would work as follows:

each user has a page that only they can access (or one page that loads from logged-in user) and on this page they can view information about people they referred ( sign-up date, Name, country, etc), the people they referred, and the people that they referred (4 generations counting the original user).

the client is willing to manually enter the information as people sign-up.

I'm just not sure the best way to input this info and link it to a user.

What is the best way to handle this kind of request?

Things I've considered:

-Custom post type (a lot of work to maintain, with a full post for each user)

-additional fields on the user, perhaps using CIMY USER EXTRA FIELDS (not sure how to get multiple data connected to a single "descendant" user)

-buddypress, to use their xprofile functionality (more to setup and more overhead on the site)

Answer (score 0):

Something I completely missed:  use an array as a user_meta value.  I had thought arrays weren't accepted by *_user_meta().  looks like I was wrong and this should make things much easier.